# How to apply unix2dos on last modified file?

Tags: shell, unix

Ok, so I have a few files in my directory which follows the following pattern:

```
TEST_20150130.txt
TEST_20150202.txt
TEST_20150203.txt
TEST_20150204.txt
TEST_RESULT_20150130.csv
TEST_RESULT_20150202.csv
TEST_RESULT_20150203.csv
TEST_RESULT_20150204.csv
```

Now I want to apply the command unix2dos, but only on TEST_20150204.txt and TEST_RESULT_20150204.csv

Would anyone be able to suggest what would be the easiest one liner script that could do this?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (but not necessarily the most robust):

```
unix2dos `\ls -rtd DIR_NAME/* | tail -2`
```

This is easy and will surely work on your example, but you should also be aware that in general [you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) like that.

Comment: Thanks, this looks to be a good and simple way to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below command too... Depends you only want to modify today's file or only last file ...

```
unix2dos `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -daystart -mtime -1`
```

Comment: Does this one only look only at today's file? I'm looking to modify the last 2 files only, no need to check when it was produced